# How to retrieve certain elements from xml data with Linq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This xml data is a little tricky for me, it is structured like so:

```
<site time="local">
    <key>000-000-000</key>
    <valid-time period-name="Monday">2012-09-03T06:00:00-04:00</valid-time>
    <valid-time period-name="Tuesday">2012-09-04T06:00:00-04:00</valid-time>
    <valid-time period-name="Wednesday">2012-09-05T06:00:00-04:00</valid-time>
    <valid-time period-name="Thursday">2012-09-06T06:00:00-04:00</valid-time>
 </site>
 <site time="local">
    <key>123-456-789</key>
    <valid-time period-name="Monday">2012-09-03T06:00:00-04:00</valid-time>
    <valid-time period-name="Tuesday">2012-09-04T06:00:00-04:00</valid-time>
    <valid-time period-name="Wednesday">2012-09-05T06:00:00-04:00</valid-time>
    <valid-time period-name="Thursday">2012-09-06T06:00:00-04:00</valid-time>
 </site>
...more <site time="">...
```

I am doing this to get the data:

```
xmlCurrent = from d in Xmldata.Descendants("site")
                        .Where(s => s.Element("key").Value.Equals("123-456-789"))
                        .Select(x => new { content = x.Value})
                        .ToList();
```

But all the content is going into one index of the list as a single string, how do I get each value into a different index?

Answer (score 2):

Your current code selects `<site>` elements.

You probably want something more like:

```
  xmlCurrent = from d in Xmldata.Descendants("site")
               where d.Element("key").Value.Equals("123-456-789")
               select d.Elements("valid-time");
```

That would give you an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>>`, maybe you'll want to flatten it.

```
//untested
IEnumerable<XElement> current =  Xmldata
     .Descendants("site")
     .Where(s => s.Element("key").Value.Equals("123-456-789") )
     .SelectMany(s => s.Elements("valid-time") );
```

Comment: `SelectMany()` would flatten it, but it doesn't have a query syntax equivalent, does it?

Comment: yeah xmlCurrent is a XElement so the compiler gives an error "Cannot implicitly convert type"

Comment: It should not be a (single) XElement. That's an error in the declaration of xmlCurrent, not the query.

Comment: @Jack, maybe you want to apply something like `FirstOrDefault()` to the result of the query in order to obtain a single element, but this is not clear from your question, as your sample query returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>` in the first place.

Comment: `SelectMany` in query syntax  actually is  more naturally than method syntax: just repeat multiple `froms`: `from f in foos from b in f.bars select b;`

Comment: @TimSchmelter - you're right but I'll leave the Extension methods up just from personal preference.

Comment: @Tim, so you chain `froms`. Excellent. Many thanks for that tip :)